# Custom maximum window width and height?

Tags: windows

*environment*: I'm on Windows, I have XP and 7, so both are interesting to me. Plan to install some Linux so that's relevant too.

*problem*: I have enough screen space, and maximizing a window often makes them just 'too big' for me.

Of course I can hand-size them all the way I want. But it would be convenient if I could set up a window width/height size automatically.

I imagine something like this: I press a keyboard button or a GUI button, and the window is resized to say 520x490 (would be my custom setting). Problem is I can do this with the browser via addons but not with any OS window (that is resizable).

The best would be if I could do this per app, and also provide a default for the apps I have not specified.

It doesn't have to override the maximize button and other normal buttons but if that's what it takes it's ok too. But I'd like to remain able to *move meanwhile* and *later resize* them if I want.

**Is there a way to resize OS windows easily to a stored preferred width and height?**

**UPDATE 1**: if I resize the window manually after it was set to the 'preferred size', later I should be able to resize it again to the 'preferred size' easily, without closing/reopening it.

On the other hand, position is *not* a requirement. If it is saved, it is better as optional.

Answer (score 2):

`To force Windows to record the size of a window and set it as the default size for that program each time it's opened, simply resize the window to your preferred size, then hold the CTRL key while you click the X to close it. The program should use that size as the default size until changed (by resizing then closing).`

[Source](http://help.wfu.edu/public/computers/standard-load-software/windows-7---set-default-window-size)

For Linux, see this SE link https://askubuntu.com/questions/8834/how-do-i-save-remember-last-used-window-position-and-size-for-applications

Comment: didn't know about it! very nice! but can it resize to this size without closing/reopening the window?

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to deal with "too much space" on the screen.

One is to use window manager like for example [Winsplit Revolution](http://winsplit-revolution.com/). This program enables you to easily move window to preset positions (lef, right, top, bottom, middle) and you can also customize and add the positions.

If you however just want to save position for the each window, you can use [WinSize2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winsize2/) that enables you to save position of each window as default position. When you open it next time, it will open it there.

Both solutions should work on both Windows XP and Windows 7. Don't know about  similar programs for Linux since I'm not using it.

Comment: I'm not quite concerned about their position but I'm concerned about their size (dimensions). Can Winsplit remember the size? Position should be only optional. Also once a window is up, Winsplit would set the right dimensions; but if I resize the window can it set the size again if I want it to?

Comment: updated my question to reflect these questions

Comment: Winsplit only serves as a sort of template for positioning windows on screen. It will not remember size or position of windows. But it makes moving and resizing windows very fast, since you only need to click few buttons.

Comment: I see, hm. Not exactly what I'm looking for. Rather it reminds you of tiling window managers. But will give it a try.